# Is there a string hash function that supports h(x) + h(y) = h(x+y)

Tags: java, hash, hashcode

I'm trying to save space by using hash values of strings. I have a very specific requirement, the simplified description of which is as follows:

I have two sets of string values and a value is provided in runtime. I need to get a list of all strings from the second set that starts with a string from the first set and ends with the query value. Here is a significantly simplified representation and description:

```
set1:
my_test_val_1
my_test_val_2

set2:
my_test_val_1_extended_to_another_value
my_test_val_2_extended_as_well
```

My aim is to keep hash values of these sets as in:

```
set1:
hash(my_test_val_1)
...

set2:
hash(my_test_val_1_extended_to_another_value)
```

to save on space and when '_extended_to_another_value' arrives as a query, use the hash function with distributive property over addition to do:

```
hash(my_test_val_1) + hash('_extended_to_another_value') = hash_value_to_search
```

My search attempts to find a hash function that supports this property has failed most probably due to not using the right keywords for search, so even if you can describe the right terms for what I'm describing above, it would help

Comment: Are you relying on *just* keeping the hashes? What's your plan for dealing with hash collisions?

Comment: What properties do you require from the resulting hash function? How many bits may be used for the final hash?

Comment: " need to get a list of all strings from the second set that starts with a string from the first set and ends with the query value." [Are you looking for a trie?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)

Comment: Perhaps something like a [prefix hash tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_hash_tree) would be relevant here?

Comment: @JonSkeet yes hash collisions is an issue, but I could live with a low collision rate accompanied by some extensive testing (this is all synthetic data so I can test it at large scale) to see at what rate, if any I'm having collisions.

Comment: An interesting generalisation of this question is if it is possible to find _any_ operations and hash functions _h_, _#_ and _§_ such that _h(x) # h(y) = h(x § y)_.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one:

```
import java.util.Random;
public class StringHasher {
    private static int[] CHAR_HASHES = new int[65536];
    static {
        Random rng = new Random();
        for(int k = 0; k < 65536; k++)
            CHAR_HASHES[k] = rng.nextInt();
    }
    public static int hash(String s) {
        int result = 0;
        for(int k = 0; k < s.length(); k++) {
            result += CHAR_HASHES[s.charAt(k)];
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

It turns out that any such hash *must* be constructed by adding up all the hashes of the string's constituent characters - otherwise for example `h("hello") = h("h") + h("e") + h("l") + h("l") + h("o")` would not hold.

Note: this means you cannot have a very collision-resistant hash, as every string containing the same characters will have the same hash, per the previous paragraph.

Choosing random values for the hash of each single-character string should provide close to the best possible collision resistance, on average. This does waste 256 KiB of memory, and isn't the fastest possible method, and is not repeatable, but it suffices for a proof-of-concept.

Comment: +1 for observation about consequences of hash linearity.
I would consider using primes to fill CHAR_HASHES.

Comment: @Krystian I have no idea how to go about choosing character hashes for good collision resistance (but random numbers work).

Answer (score -2):

You can use some of the mainstream hash algorithms and try to hack it with online databases. If x and y are short enough you might find it in the MD5 or SHA online cracked hashes databases and if you decypher it than you can proceed with your algorithm.

If your application is online it could use that approach. The downside is that in some corner cases you might get wrong value which has the same hash code as the right one, but the probability of that is pretty low.

This is basically a hack, but you are doing that kind of stuff with your requirement, so it might be acceptable for you.

Here is an example of online hash databases:

- http://www.md5online.org/
- http://www.dehashme.com/